# Getting query value from URL in nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is the url of api.

`http://localhost:3000/verify?id=55`

And this is the snipet for getting the query value.

```
server.get('/verify', async (req,res,next) => {
  try { console.log(req.query.id); }
  catch{err}
});
```

As the log prints out "undefined" , is there a problem on url expression?

Comment: You need a query-parser middleware to access the query like that. Are you using express?

Comment: I see. no. it is Restify.

Comment: Do you have `server.use(restify.queryParser());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look something like this (note the use of query parser middleware):

```
const restify = require('restify');

const server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'myapp',
  version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());

server.get('/verify', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.id);
});
```

Comment: Tried those middleware but now got the following error.
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"caused by TypeError: req.query is not a function"}.

Comment: It worked after updating npm packages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this once

```
server.get('/verify', async (req,res,next) => {
try { 
  var id = JSON.parse(req.query.id); 
}
  catch{err}
});
```